# Clickhouse now() with milliseconds

Tags: datetime, clickhouse

I'm trying to get a current datetime in the Clickhouse. There is function `now()` that could I use but the precision is just in seconds

```
select now();
-- result 2022-05-05 10:34:48


select toUnixTimestamp(now());
-- result 1651746940
```

Any idea how could I get the current datetime with a milliseconds precision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `now64` function

```sql
select now64();

-- 2022-05-05 10:57:32.953
```

[There are related -64 functions like `toUnixTimestamp64Milli()` etc.](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions#tounixtimestamp64milli)

Comment: thanks a lot, I was surprised that I did not find it in the documentation. As I see it is already listed as an issue on Github https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/14634